# Specifying multiple ids (AlternateId ) in the ConvertId EWS request?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I was under an impression that I can pass multiple ids in the ConvertId request. If I send the following request with two ids (they happen to be folder and its child message), I only get one id back.

Sure sounds like a bug...

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Header>
            <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <m:ConvertId DestinationFormat="EwsId">
                <m:SourceIds>
                    <AlternateId Format="EntryId" Id="AAAAAF6BdU8APhVJsGWfKuqS58IBAMfPIwTHe/ZFheiJLdb/e6wAAAAAAQwAAA==" Mailbox="user@domain.demo"/>
                    <AlternateId Format="EntryId" Id="AAAAAF6BdU8APhVJsGWfKuqS58IHAMfPIwTHe/ZFheiJLdb/e6wAAAAAAQwAAEp86F7RqydMniCqPL+oKLEAAeNW8FMAAA==" Mailbox="user@domain.demo"/>
                </m:SourceIds>
             </m:ConvertId>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

And the response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
            <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="V2018_01_08" MinorBuildNumber="31" MajorBuildNumber="1228" MinorVersion="20" MajorVersion="15"/>
        </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <m:ConvertIdResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:ConvertIdResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:AlternateId Mailbox="user@domain.demo" Id="AQMkAGU2ZWM5ZTQwLTk0MjMtNDY3NS1iZWI5LWQ4NTA0MDhmM2U0OQBGAAADXoF1TwA+FUmwZZ8q6pLnwgcAx88jBMd79kWF6Ikt1v97rAAAAgEMAAAASnzoXtGrJ0yeIKo8v6gosQAB41bwUwAAAA==" Format="EwsId" xsi:type="t:AlternateIdType"/>
                </m:ConvertIdResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:ConvertIdResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**EDIT:**
An example of two ids (two messages) request worling as expected.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <ConvertId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
               DestinationFormat="EwsId">
      <SourceIds>
        <t:AlternateId Format="EntryId"
                       Id="AAAAAF6BdU8APhVJsGWfKuqS58IHAMfPIwTHe/ZFheiJLdb/e6wAAAAAAQwAAEp86F7RqydMniCqPL+oKLEAAiLXM0AAAA=="
                       Mailbox="user@domain.demo"/>
        <t:AlternateId Mailbox="user@domain.demo" 
                       Id="AAAAAF6BdU8APhVJsGWfKuqS58IHAMfPIwTHe/ZFheiJLdb/e6wAAAAAAQwAAEp86F7RqydMniCq PL+oKLEAAiC+eEMAAA==" 
                       Format="EntryId"/>

      </SourceIds>
    </ConvertId>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="1273" MinorBuildNumber="26" Version="V2018_01_08" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  </s:Header><s:Body><m:ConvertIdResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <m:ResponseMessages>
    <m:ConvertIdResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
      <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
      <m:AlternateId xsi:type="t:AlternateIdType" Format="EwsId" Id="AQMkAGU2ZWM5ZTQwLTk0MjMtNDY3NS1iZWI5LWQ4NTA0MDhmM2U0OQBGAAADXoF1TwA+FUmwZZ8q6pLnwgcAx88jBMd79kWF6Ikt1v97rAAAAgEMAAAASnzoXtGrJ0yeIKo8v6gosQACItczQAAAAA==" Mailbox="user@domain.demo"/>
    </m:ConvertIdResponseMessage>
    <m:ConvertIdResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
      <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
      <m:AlternateId xsi:type="t:AlternateIdType" Format="EwsId" Id="AQMkAGU2ZWM5ZTQwLTk0MjMtNDY3NS1iZWI5LWQ4NTA0MDhmM2U0OQBGAAADXoF1TwA+FUmwZZ8q6pLnwgcAx88jBMd79kWF6Ikt1v97rAAAAgEMAAAASnzoXtGrJ0yeIKo8v6gosQACIL54QwAAAA==" Mailbox="user@domain.demo"/>
    </m:ConvertIdResponseMessage>
  </m:ResponseMessages>
  </m:ConvertIdResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: This is against Office 365 Exchange Server, so it is the latest and greatest...

Comment: Interesting. Please identify/point to any MS provided or 3rdP provided documentation / guidance (talk or video) where it directly / indirectly states that this is possible. I have never seen or heard of any technical guidance / use case document, from MS or 3rdP information where this is a stated use case. I just did a sanity check of all resources I have collected over the last 2 years relative to this AlternateId/ConvertId data points and the info from MSIgnite2018, and it's not part of any presentation. If ADFS 3x is in the mix, the this sort of multiple stuff has been a no go to date.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/sourceids

Comment: "The SourceIds element contains the source identifiers to convert." Note the plural.

Comment: Try it - pass entry ids of two messages, you get back two converted ids: See the updated question above

Comment: That I get, and have done, as I've always understood to be a singular object type case. Meaning user identity or object identity (mailbox object), not mixed as you show in your first post. Hence the pointer request, which is already in my stash, and I did look at that before posting back. I am not sure if that is the catch 22 regarding this, but worth troubleshooting.

Comment: I see what you mean - only one type (messages) or another (folders) is allowed at the same time, but not both.I just tried folder and message (different from the one I tried above) in the same request, and I got back 2 ids.. Go figure...

Comment: Yeppers, I did test again, and meant to post back earlier (just got back online just now), but you beat me to it. I had never tried to mix because that was not how I was taught / read regarding the use of it.

Comment: I think you missed my point - I passed a message and a folder entry id - and I got back two converted ids. So it does **not** have to be the same kind.

Answer (score 0):

***Corrections***

So, consolidating our exchange so it can be seen as the answer to date.

As per the sanity testing of this method by myself and  Dmitry Streblechenko (the OP). In leveraging this method, multiples are allowed.
 For example: only one type (messages) or another (folders) is allowed at the same time.

Comment: Different types are allowed, please see my comment above.